# php записать в ini файл

Tags: php

Есть ini файл со значением

```
AdminLogin = admin
```

Как переменную в  ini перезаписать?

Answer (score 1):

Сам разобрался. 
Сначала получаю массив

```
$conf = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
$login = $conf['user']['AdminLogin'];
```

Потом собственно его редактирую

```
$conf['user']['AdminLogin'] = $_POST['adminlogin'];
```

Далее обрабатываю массив функцией

```
function arr2ini(array $a, array $parent = array())
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v))
        {
            //subsection case
            //merge all the sections into one array...
            $sec = array_merge((array) $parent, (array) $k);
            //add section information to the output
            $out .= '[' . join('.', $sec) . ']' . PHP_EOL;
            //recursively traverse deeper
            $out .= arr2ini($v, $sec);
        }
        else
        {
            //plain key->value case
            $out .= "$k=$v" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

И записываю в файл

```
    $inisave = arr2ini($conf);
    $file_handle = fopen("config.ini", "w");
    fwrite($file_handle, $inisave); 
    fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде никак. Решается только полной перезаписью файла.

Т.е. сначала считали файл, получили из него переменные. Одну из них поменяли и потом опять записали все переменные в файл.

Comment: как это сделать?